# Flutter: How to center ClipOval child

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to set the background color of an `IconButton`

Here is my code

```
ClipOval(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 50.0,
                      width: 50.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: IconButton(
                        color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.8),
                        iconSize: 50.0,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
```

Here is the result

[image]

How can I make the oval `Container` and the `IconButton` the same size and all centered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `Container`'s `width` and `height` property because you are already using `iconSize` in `IconButton`. Either remove `iconSize` or `width/height` in `Container`

Screenshot:

[image]

```
ClipOval(
  child: Material(
    color: Colors.green,
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Icon(
        Icons.add,
        color: Colors.white,
        size: 50,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```